# View TLS Certificate in Safari 8 / Yosemite

Tags: safari, macos, certificate, ssl

i've installed the new OS X Yosemite recently. Now i'm trying to view the TLS Certificate and the Certificate Chain in the new Safari.
In the older versions of Safari one just had to click onto the padlock to view the connection properties.

I know, it's all possible by using another Browser, but i like the new Safari ;-)

Best regards, Jonas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The padlock should still be there

[image: HTTPS connection to Google]

and by clicking on it, you get the certificate information as before:

[image: Secure connection information]

Clicking on «Show Certificate» gives the details:

[image: Certificate details]

Comment: Well you are right, even though it's kind of hard to hit. Obviously I wasn't able to... 

Thank you Matteo!

Comment: Note that URLs with some kind of path won't show the padlock, so you get the padlock only on the base domain. This works pretty bad with sites that redirect, I had to disable javascript to be able to get the padlock on the root domain for some sites.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz Thanks I'll edit the answer although I suppose it is a bug. There are sites, as you said, where there is no way to get the certificate ...

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz Where you able to understand when it is shown and when not? For example https://www.google.ch/intl/en/about/ shows a padlock while https://www.ethz.ch/de.html not.

Comment: Note that this padlock might not show up if the site contains links to insecure content or assets (like images, stylesheets or scripts). Use ⌥⌘C to open the Error Console.

Comment: Here's an [useful tool](https://www.whynopadlock.com) that can check your website and tell you "why no padlock?". ;)

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole is think, that's exactly the problem. You cannot debug certificate problems or just have a quick glimpse if there's anything wrong with the cert without running an extra tool (which is really annoying). I'm struggling with this removed feature since they killed it.